# How to filter a pandas dataframe to just the rows that show change within a group?

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe that I would like to filter down to only the rows that first show change in a certain column within a group.

For example, my dataframe looks like this:

| GROUP | DATE | QUANTITY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2020-01-01 | 2 |
| A | 2020-01-02 | 2 |
| A | 2020-01-03 | 3 |
| A | 2020-01-04 | 2 |
| B | 2020-01-01 | 1 |
| B | 2020-01-04 | 2 |
| C | 2020-01-01 | 3 |
| C | 2020-01-06 | 2 |
| C | 2020-01-07 | 2 |

I would like to be able to produce the table below:

| GROUP | DATE | QUANTITY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2020-01-01 | 2 |
| A | 2020-01-03 | 3 |
| A | 2020-01-04 | 2 |
| B | 2020-01-01 | 1 |
| B | 2020-01-04 | 2 |
| C | 2020-01-01 | 3 |
| C | 2020-01-06 | 2 |

So that we only keep the first row when QUANTITY changes within the group when sorted by date.

How can I achieve this without resorting to an inefficient for loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert to a `datetime` and sort the values. Then using `shift` create a mask that keeps rows where the group changes (i.e. first row within group) or the value changes; logically equivalent to keeping rows within group where the quantity changes.

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
df = df.sort_values(['GROUP', 'DATE'])

m = (df['QUANTITY'].ne(df['QUANTITY'].shift())   # Quanity Changes
    | df['GROUP'].ne(df['GROUP'].shift()))       # Group Changes

df[m]
```

---

```
  GROUP       DATE  QUANTITY
0     A 2020-01-01         2
2     A 2020-01-03         3
3     A 2020-01-04         2
4     B 2020-01-01         1
5     B 2020-01-04         2
6     C 2020-01-01         3
7     C 2020-01-06         2
```